# Canadian census divisions in R: cannot open

Tags: r

I'm trying to follow the first part of the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078193/canadian-census-map-division-in-r), copied and pasted below:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)

# decent, uncluttered map theme (needs devtools package tho)
devtools::source_gist("https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")

# grab the file from "Statistics Canada"
download.file("http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/gcd_000b11a_e.zip",
              destfile="gcd_000b11a_e.zip")

unzip("gcd_000b11a_e.zip")

# this simplifies the polygons so they load/plot faster
system("ogr2ogr canada.shp gcd_000b11a_e.shp -simplify 0.01")

# what layers do we have? you can use this to check
#   ogrListLayers("gcd_000b11a_e/canada.shp")
# but there are none, so the shapefile is the layer

canada <- readOGR("gcd_000b11a_e/","canada")

# do this to see what's available from an "identifier" standpoint
# "CDNAME" seems to be the census district name
# "PRNAME" seems to be the province name
# str(canada@data)

# rig up  some data
# make a data frame of census division areas
# you can assign as many value columns as you like
# they get merged in later and can be used as the fill level
# we'll use the area as the fill level
map_areas <- data.frame(id=canada@data$CDNAME,
                        area=sapply(slot(canada, "polygons"), slot, "area") )

# this takes a while, but it makes a data frame for use with
# ggplot and lets us use the census division name for doing things
# like applying colors
canada_map <- fortify(canada, region="CDNAME")

# merge in areas
canada_map <- merge(canada_map, map_areas, by="id")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=canada_map, map=canada_map,
                    aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=log1p(area)),
                    color="white", size=0.1)
gg <- gg + coord_map() # can choose other projections
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

However, I get several errors. The first is:

```
system("ogr2ogr canada.shp gcd_000b11a_e.shp -simplify 0.01")
/bin/sh: ogr2ogr: command not found
```

After searching around, and reading a few ideas (e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80954/os-x-mavericks-accessing-gdal-from-terminal-issue), and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130710/system-call-gdal-function-in-r-on-mac)) I found that it's a problem with `rgdal`. I can load the `rgdal` library no problem:

```
> library(rgdal)
>
```

But then I looked for the directory /Macintosh HD/Library/Frameworks, and there is no GDAL_Frameworks subdirectory.

I am running Mac OSX Sierra, version 10.12.6, and R version 3.4.1 (Single Candle).

How can I run that `system` command properly?

Comment: what happens when you try `system("which ogr2ogr")`?

Comment: Maybe you should install ogr2ogr separately and try running it outside of R?

Comment: @Stedy I hit enter and I get the '>' sign, so the command executes successfully.

Comment: @Hack-R, not sure how to do that, as ogr2ogr is part of the rgdal library and as far as I know individual commands cannot be installed separately...

Comment: @StatsSorceress No, it's not. It's part of GDAL, which has nothing to do with R. The rgdal library just tries to include it. It doesn't always work. So you should try installing it outside of R. http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries Then you can run org2ogr from the good installation and either work around the problem or remap the R wrapper to the good installation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a problem with system paths on Mac you may alternatively provide full path to the gdal library.

`system("/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr canada.shp gcd_000b11a_e.shp -simplify 0.01")`

Above path can also be wrong, to obtain correct path run `which ogr2ogr` in Mac terminal. If this path is different than `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr` exchange with the correct one.

If you still have issue with gdal library, try to install from source and run above system command in R again
`brew install gdal-20 --build-from-source`

Comment: Hi @Gonzo, I think that requires me to have homebrew installed, yes? Also, I don't have` /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework` - the GDAL.framework directory does not exist.

Comment: Homebrew is strongly recommended 
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`.
It seems you don't have gdal installed or it's installed wrong way. Install homebrew, than gdal from source and use full path system command in R. Should work. Enjoy!